# Why outlook msg file does not have any contentBytes? using graph microsoft api

Tags: graph, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin

I have a small script to get all my outlook mails and its attachments. And its working fine.

I can get all the mail and its attachments.  However there's particular email that i have a problem.

That email has two attachments "sample.msg" and "sample.pdf". By using this endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{message-id}/attachments` i can get it.

But why is it the sample.msg has no contentBytes?

[image]

Is there a way i can get the contentBytes for sample.msg? or there is another endpoint for that particular attachment type?

Please help me to understand this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@odata.type` [itemAttachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/itemattachment?view=graph-rest-1.0) indicates that the main message. To get the properties of the item attached to a message, you need to make a separate call and expand `item` relationship

```
GET /v1.0/me/messages/{message_id}/attachments/{attachment_id}?$expand=microsoft.graph.itemattachment/item
```

Or you can get MIME raw content of the attachment

```
GET /v1.0/me/messages/{message_id}/attachments/{attachment_id}/$value
```